# Find all collections in mongodb with specific field-irrespective of nesting level

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I want Mongo DB script which list the all the collection having the specific field irrespective of the nesting level meaning if I am searching for field empId it can be directly available in one collection and in other collection it can be nested

```
Example: 
           
    case 1:{ 
                empid:1234,
                empName:test
                 
              }

    case 2(it can be nested in object1 like )
            { 
                 object1:{
                   emplId:1234,
                   empName :test
                 }                 
              }
case 3(it can be nested one object-n like )
            { 
                 object-n:{
                   emplId:1234,
                   empName :test
                 }                 
              }
```

I have Written below Script which works does not search if the field is nested in another object(its will search if if field is not nested meaning only works for case-1 it deso not work for case2 and case3)

```
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(collection) {
    if (db[collection].count({empId: {$exists: true}}) > 0) {
        print(collection);
    }
});
```

can anyone help with query to find all collections in mongodb with specific field irrespective of its nesting level

Comment: Maybe the fastest way would be to export the database into JSON file and use a text search, e.g. `grep`

Answer (score 0):

```
const $query= {
    $or: [
    {
      empid: {
        $exists: true
      }
    },
    {
     "object1.empid": {
        $exists: true 
    }]



for(let i = 0 ; i < the_bigger_n ; i++)
 {    
     query.$or.push(
        {
         [`object-${i}.empid`]: {
            $exists: true
        }
       )    
 }


       
  db.collection.find($query)
```